# SSRS URL Reports from ERP 260 Character Issue

Tags: reporting-services

New to SSRS as we are moving from and Old Crystal Reports solution. We use our ERP System to pass reports and parameters off to the SSRS Server. Things have been going OK but at times we get error like the one below. Is there anything we can do to fix this? We also get this when building reports and uploading to the Server via Visual Studio's or Report Builder. Is there really a limit or do we have a setting issue?

```
The path of the item '/jomarproduction/QC/ Transaction_Scrap' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash. (rsInvalidItemPath) Get Online Help
```

We can run the report if we go directly to the SSRS Server and enter the Parameter but does not work when Passing them via URL from ERP.

Comment: First thing I see, is a space in the filename (path). Those will often give you problems with SSRS and other Microsoft stuff.  If you want/need file or path names with spaces, you have to escape them (with plus sign or %20)

Comment: @tgolisch  WOW you just saved me from pulling my hair out!!! That was the issue. However, we have seen this on other occasion mostly when building reports and such. Any idea what could cause it. Thank you for seeing that.